# Does Bootstrap's container stop providing border at a certain browser width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a responsive website.

[image]

So far it looks good. I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="products-block">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <p>...paragraph here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I resize it to a width of 768px, it seems like there's no more padding on the container.

[image]

Is container's padding affected by the size of the viewport?

Comment: `.container` class always has padding left and right 15px. If viewport is greater than 768px then `.container` class gets a fixed width. The "padding" you see is probably the left and right margins.

Answer (score 0):

this is bootstrap's media query, the width of the container is changing and not the padding.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px; // 1200px and up
}    
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px; //992 - 1199px 
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px; //768 - 991px
}
```